# Replace HTTP protocol with FTP to download large files

Tags: swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I am considering using Hawkbit + SWUpdate to manage my update environment.

I am wondering if it is possible to use FTP protocol to download the update image, instead of HTTP protocol, as my update image is quite large.

I couldn't find any information about it.

Thank you very much !

Julien.

Comment: Why the FTP protocol would be an improvement for large files? HTTP can handle any file size as well.